# Insert id's into script tags using grunt

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-contrib-concat

I want to insert id into the script tag

gruntfile.js

```
var obj = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'];
var i = 0;

grunt.initConfig({
    concat:{
                    basic:{
                        options:{                               
                            banner:'<script type="text/ng-template" id=' +obj[i] + ' >',
                            separator:'</script><script type="text/ng-template" id=' + obj[i++] + ' >',
                            footer:'</script>'
                        },
                        files:[{
                            src:['./src/folder/*.html'],
                            dest:'./src/foler/index.ftl'
                        }]
                    }
        }
})
```

but on the output when the files are concated into index.ftl all the ids have the same id='id3'

how can I get the final concatinated file with all unique ids.

Answer (score 0):

The following link solves the part of this question of adding ID, 
I had created my own wrap plugin and used it in the code to added id's dynamically,

[Replace all the text with specified replacement using grunt replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29662570/replace-all-the-text-with-specified-replacement-using-grunt-replace)